# Rails App- postgresql - learning to use copy command - location of db on mac OSX?

Tags: postgresql, copy

Hi Im learning how to use postgresql's COPY command to import data in from a csv file on my local drive onto the postgresql db of my rails app.

The first step is how do I find the location of postgresql on my local drive?

Wouldn't I need it to call the COPY command?

I have pg3admin which I can see as a gui, it has all my databases. but where would I be calling the copy command from?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `COPY` into a table `FROM` a file, the file must be accessible to the OS user running the PostgreSQL server, or (more commonly) to the OS user running your client.  In the latter case, you `COPY tablename FROM STDIN`, and your client application feeds the file to the server.  To do this in psql you use \copy.

Answer (score 0):

Most of postgres lives (assuming you're using a *nix OS) in `/var/lib/pgsql`. The postgres [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/storage-file-layout.html) has more info about where files are commonly found, and what each file does.

Comment: The location of those files is completely irrelevant when using `COPY`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not completely, no. If you give a relative path to `COPY` it'll look for a file within the datadir.